# Recompiling less files - modifyVars not compiling some elements

Tags: less

I'm trying to apply a less file to a specific div and then modify it with javascript, and I'm running into problems. Here's what I've got:

```
<div id="live">
    <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

less:

```
@body-bg: #fff;

#live {
    @import "bootstrap/scaffolding.less";
}
```

Then I'm compiling it on the fly. The initial compilation works, giving the body tag from bootstrap the @body-bg variable. So then I try to modify it with:

```
less.modifyVars({'@body-bg':'blue'});
```

But this doesn't re-compile the files inside #live. Does anyone know how you can force it to recompile the whole file?

Here's the modifyVars() function of less.js:

```
less.modifyVars = function (a) {
    var b = "";
    for (var c in a) b += ("@" === c.slice(0, 1) ? "" : "@") + c + ": " + (";" === a[c].slice(-1) ? a[c] : a[c] + ";");
    less.refresh(!1, b)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the `watch` mode set in LESS for an automatic update. To quote [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org):

> *Watch mode* is a client-side feature which enables your styles to refresh automatically as they are changed.
>
> To enable it, append `#!watch` to the browser URL, then refresh the page. Alternatively, you can run `less.watch()` from the console.

Comment: You can call it to refresh with lee.modifyVars() too, but I'm just wondering why it only updates part of the less file and leaves everything inside #live {}.